# Jquery Hover Animation Queing

Tags: jquery, animation, queue

I have built this markup with 3 squares. On hover of any of the squares, the middle horizontal bar will perform 2 animations:

1. animate the margin
2. animate the height

I've followed the tutorial [http://css-tricks.com/full-jquery-animations/][1] But because there are two animations is seems to conflict with the other animation once the mouse hovers and allows the queue to build.  To reproduce, try moving your mouse violently across the 3 cells.

See my JS Fiddle here: [http://jsfiddle.net/xtTcv/][2]

HTML:

```
<div id="home-feature-wrapper">
    <div class="home-feature">
        <img src="/5e7uj.jpg" alt="aerobed feature" />
        <div class="home-feature-text">
            <a href="#"><span class="feature-text-top">CHECKOUT</span><br />
                <span class="feature-text-bottom">OUR SPECIALS</span> 
            </a>
        <div class="home-feature-details">                
            <p>Don't miss out on items specially discounted for our web store!</p>
            <a href="#" class="button">CLICK HERE</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="home-feature">
    <img src="5e7uj.jpg" alt="aerobed feature" />
    <div class="home-feature-text">
        <a href="#"><span class="feature-text-top">SIGN UP</span><br />
            <span class="feature-text-bottom">FOR SAVINGS</span> 
        </a>
        <div class="home-feature-details">
            [[ConLib:SubscribeToEmailList Caption="Subscribe To Email List" EmailListId="1"]]
            <p>Sign up to receive the lastest news on special coupon codes, discounts, and other money-saving deals!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="home-feature">
    <img src="5e7uj.jpg" alt="aerobed feature" />
    <div class="home-feature-text">
        <a href="#"><span class="feature-text-top">TOP SELLER</span><br />
            <span class="feature-text-bottom">PREMIUM COMFORT</span> 
        </a>
        <div class="home-feature-details">                
            <p>Shop our most popular items and see what everyone is talking about!</p>
            <a href="#" class="button">CLICK HERE</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#home-feature-wrapper {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
height: 280px;
margin: 400px auto -30px;
overflow: hidden;
padding-right: 5px;
width: 972px;
z-index: 1;
}
#home-feature-wrapper img {
margin: 10px 5px 10px 0;
}
#home-feature-wrapper img:first-child {
margin-left: 10px;
}
#home-feature-wrapper .home-feature {
float: left;
height: 272px;
overflow: hidden;
}
#home-feature-wrapper .home-feature-text {
background: url("http://css-tricks.com/wp-content/csstricks-uploads/transpBlue75.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
color: #FFFFFF;
height: 62px;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: -182px;
overflow: hidden;
padding-top: 18px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
width: 309px;
}
#home-feature-wrapper .home-feature-text a {
color: #FFFFFF;
}
#home-feature-wrapper .home-feature-text .feature-text-top {
font-size: 20px;
}
#home-feature-wrapper .home-feature-text .home-feature-details {
border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
margin: 30px 20px 20px;
padding: 10px;
}
#home-feature-wrapper .home-feature-text .home-feature-details .widget div.innerSection div.header h2 {
font-size: 10px;
}
#home-feature-wrapper .home-feature-text .home-feature-details .widget div.innerSection .compactleft tbody tr th label#ctl00_ctl00_NestedMaster_PageContent_ctl00_UserEmailLabel {
display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(".home-feature").hover(function () { 
    $(".home-feature-text", this).filter(':not(:animated)').animate({ marginTop: "-272px" });
    $(".home-feature-text", this).animate({ height: "244px" }); 
}, function () { 
    $(".home-feature-text", this).animate({ marginTop: "-182px" }); 
    $(".home-feature-text", this).animate({ height: "62px" }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for:

```
  $(".home-feature-text", this).stop(true).animate({ height: "62px", marginTop: "-182px"});
```

Comment: Very close! But the marginTop did not animate back to vertical center on mouseout. I think I got it tough. $(".home-feature-text", this).stop(true).animate({ marginTop: "-182px" });

Answer (score 0):

Not placing the animation on the queue will stop the queue from building up:

```
$(".home-feature-text", this).animate({ height: "62px" }, { queue: false });
```